# Angular + Asp.Net MVC. Where is the "data"?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

Angular method:

```
addSubject() {
    const data = {
        name: this.subject.name, 
        description: this.subject.description, 
        teachersCount: this.subject.teachersCount,
        type: this.subject.type
    }
        
    this.http.post("https://localhost:7042/Subject/addsubject", data).subscribe(res => console.log(res.toString()))
}
```

url spelled correctly.

Asp.Net MVC - How to get the data?

```
public string AddSubject()
{
        var data = "How to get the 'Data'?";
        return "OK";
}
```

How to get the data in Asp Net MVC method?

I tried:

```
var data = Request.Form["data"]
```

```
var data = Request.Query["data"]
```

```
public string AddSubject(object data)
{
        return "OK";
}
```

Comment: You can grab the data via parameters or wrap them in an object. For example:
`public string AddSubject(string name, string description, int teachersCount, string type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the data via parameters or wrap them in an object.
For example with parameters:

```
public string AddSubject(string name, string description, int teachersCount, string type)
```

Or alternatively you can use a class to do this:

```
public string AddSubject(SubjectData data)
```

You can then create a class like this:

```
public class SubjectData 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    int TeachersCount { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The values will be bound to that object by the framework.